# Mongo DB C# serializer - circular reference

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a complex model I want to persist to Mongo DB. This model has some circular reference I don't want to break.

Apparently I can't do that with the official Mongo C# driver. 
Json.Net can serialize properly in Bson, and handle my model without any problem.

Can I change the mongo driver serializer ? Or do you have any other suggestion to handle this case (other than just avoid circular reference or ignore property) ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't break the connections, there are a number of options for doing custom serialization.

I'd start here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/serialize-documents-with-the-csharp-driver/

In particular, the section entitled "Write a Custom Serializer." You'll need to decide whether the potential extra complexity is worth it.

Or, you could consider converting the objects to json, then to a BsonDocument.

```
BsonDocument document = BsonDocument.Parse(json);
```

If you do need this extensively, just note that you are doing a reasonably significant amount of busy work with the Object->JSON->BsonDocument->Bson path. It's something to consider if you need high throughput or are concerned about CPU/memory utilization.

Comment: If JSON.NET properly serializes the object then I highly suggest converting the JSON directly to a BSON document. This will avoid the complexity of a custom serializer to recreate something that already works. Good solution @WiredPrairie.

Comment: Ok, So I suppose I cannot just serialize directly in bson with json.net, and send the result to mongoDB. I absolutely need the step with bsonDocument.Parse ?!

Comment: It needs to be in a structure that can be serialized. If you don't want to do that, write a custom serializer. It would be the most efficient, but hardest to do. I'm not sure if you're going to be happy with the results if you convert to JSON->BSON and back as it may not be precisely what you want. Having a circular reference in a serialized document structure is going to require extra work.

Comment: Ok, I'm just surprised that no one has already solved this problem.  I'll try with the custom serializer, thank you.

Comment: You may find something, but really the issue is building a structure that fits well for your MongoDb queries. Your complex models may not query well.

Answer (score 3):

Customized serialization/deserialization is a good solution, but it does not have to be painful.  The simplest way may be for your model to use the ISupportInitialize interface, and implement the BeginInit() and EndInit() methods.

Sergio Costa has a good example of using this interface to deal with circular references on a web page titled [Serializing circular references in MongoDb](https://coderwall.com/p/gnvypw).